# 2 variable non linear search algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search, regression, curve-fitting

I have a function defined by 2 variables. The function itself is unknown. but if I input the 2 variables I get an output.

Both the variables are bounded. If I have a specific valued output, is there a relatively decent algorithm to do a search and find the corresponding variables?

Edit1: I would require both the variables 'a' and 'b' to be found. We can assume that the variables 'a' and 'b' is bounded by 0 < a < 1 and 0 < b < 10.

Also to make the search easier, we can assume that both a and b will only come in multiples of 0.1.

By doing a brute search, I could get all the multiple answers in 40 minutes. But I would require a faster method.

I have attached a sample image of the function. But this is not the case always.

[image: 3 D Plot]

Comment: @GuyGreer I believe that Newton's method usually requires the derivative of the function.  Unless the OP also has a call that returns the derivative of the function for two variables, that could be a problem.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Yeah, at first I thought he meant he was minimizing the function.  You can approximate the Jacobian from the function values though, so that's still a possible solution.

Comment: Are you looking for all the solutions to f(a,b) = c or just one?

Comment: All the solutions. Basically after getting all the multiple solutions from this I can filter the right one out using another criteria.

Comment: Seems like the issue here might actually be the amount of work that needs done to find the output rather than simply reducing the search space. Do you have access to this function? Or is it a black box you put numbers into, wait half a minute, then get an output? Overall, I'm with @RBarryYoung, I'm really questioning your function if it takes about 30 seconds to get an output. There aren't many things that would take that long, and many that do have more efficient ways of calculation for querying.

Comment: @Nuclearman Yes I have access to the function. It's a fairly large function with lot of input parameters. But a and b are the only ones I'm keeping as variables. I get the output as ray parameters(ray position coordinates, angles etc). And the above plot is basically ray y coordinate vs a and b.

Comment: You might want to consider adjusting/optimizing the function then to reduce the computation time via reducing redundancy though it'll probably require an in-depth analysis of your function to determine where redundancy can be reduced (if at all). Break the function into a number of sub-functions, from here you can do a lot of things, like [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) of the input/output to each subfunction. Also given that you know the out of that sub-function to `a=10, b=10`, adjusting that output for `a=10,b=9.9` may be faster than directly computing it.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have so little information about the function's behavior and properties and that you do not have any analytical way to get it's derivative, your best bet is probably some version of the [False-Position Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_position_method).

Comment: This will only get you one point that solves the function, where the OP said he wants the "variables".  I don't know if he means he wants all of them, because that's much more work.  Once one point is found, the problem then becomes tracing (parametrizing) the level set of the function passing through that point.  Of course if the level set consists of several connected components, this will only find one connected component.

Comment: @GuyGreer Yeah, I thought that by "*variables*" the OP was referring to the fact that there are 2 input variables, but you are right it is ambiguous.  Trying to numerically find the entire input set for a specific output of an undefined function is no trivial thing though...

Comment: Yeah I would require both the variables 'a' and 'b' to be found. We can assume that the variables 'a' and 'b' is bounded by 0<a<1 and 1<b<10. Also that both a and b will only come in multiples of 0.1. By doing a brute search, I could get all the multiple answers in 40 minutes. But I need a faster method.

Comment: When you find one solution you can find the whole connected component of the level set by travelling along the function perpendicular to the gradient of the function at that point.

Comment: Another way is to create an interpolation function (probably piece-wise) that is easier to analyse piece by piece and put all the solutions together after that.  Either a first or second order polynomial may be sufficient, but higher order polynomials are possible too.

Comment: @RahulK you say: "*variables 'a' and 'b' is bounded by 0<a<1 and 1<b<10. Also that both a and b will only come in multiples of 0.1*".  Doesn't that mean that there are only 900 total combined input values?  You should be able to check all of them a lot faster than 40 seconds.

Comment: @RBarryYoung depends on the function that is being evaluated.  And it was 40 minutes...

Comment: @RBarryYoung In total there are only less than 1000 values. But these values are not available to me readily. I have to input the variables and get the value for each set of variables. The function is complicated and this calculation takes time. So I have to minimize the number of times I'm calling the function. Also it takes me 40 minutes, not 40 seconds.